# Keep substring that precedes an expression in SQLite

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite, varchar

I want to split a varchar column on a certain expression and keep the left hand side of the result.

My column looks as follows:

| varchar_col |
| --- |
| keep_this__discard_this |
| keep_this_too__discard_this |

I want to split all the strings on the double underscore (`'__'`) and keep whatever comes before it. How can this be done in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select substr(varchar_col, 1, instr(varchar_col, '__') - 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f9ce00e1f82c094b53f4e677a1673fba) is a db<>fiddle.